# Chamada de ajax com Jquery a cada X segundos

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando fazer uma chamada `Ajax` assim que a página carrega e uma a cada 2 minutos.

A 1ª e a 2ª funciona, mas não tem 3ª chamada e por diante.

```
      <script type="text/javascript">

            function CarregarJSON() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "get",
                    url: "/Extranet/Monitor/DadosServerIISJson",
                    success: function (data) {
                    CPUIIS = data.CPU_IIS;
                    $("#CPUIIS").html(CPUIIS);
    //remoção de código para facilitar visualização

                    }

                });

                $.ajax({
                    type: "get",
                    url: "/Extranet/Monitor/DadosServerSQLJson",
                    success: function (data) {
       //remoção de código para facilitar visualização
                    }

                });
            }



            $(document).ready(function () {
                CarregarJSON();

                timeout = setTimeout(function () {
                    CarregarJSON()
                }, 12000);

            })
        </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insere a chamada do novo Ajax dentro da callback. Assim garantes que o próximo pedido só é enviado depois do segundo ajax ter chegado e garantes também que esse é o gatilho certo, ou seja, que sempre que o ajax terminar chama a função novamente.

```
function CarregarJSON() {
    var recebidas = 0;
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "/Extranet/Monitor/DadosServerIISJson",
        success: function(data) {
            if (recebidas > 0) setTimeout(CarregarJSON, 120000);
            recebidas++;
            CPUIIS = data.CPU_IIS;
            $("#CPUIIS").html(CPUIIS);
            //remoção de código para facilitar visualização
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "/Extranet/Monitor/DadosServerSQLJson",
        success: function(data) {
            if (recebidas > 0) setTimeout(CarregarJSON, 120000);
            recebidas++;
            //remoção de código para facilitar visualização
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(CarregarJSON);
```

Eventualmente podes juntar também a chamada a `CarregarJSON` (sem temporizador, ou mais curto que 2 minutos) no caso de erro assim chama logo o ajax de novo.